# Minimal and Characteristic Polynomials of Matrix Multiplication Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Fix a matrix $A \in M_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field, and consider the following linear transformation $\phi_A: M_n(F) \to M_n(F)$ given by $\phi(B) = AB$. Prove that the minimal polynomials of $\phi$ and $A$ are equal. Are their characteristic polynomials equal?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. Then for any $B$, we have $m(\phi)(B)=m(A)B=0$. Therefore, $m(x)$ also annihilates $\phi$, and so minimal polynomial of $\phi$ is divisible my $m(x)$. On the other hand, if $n(\phi)=0$ for some polynomial $n(x)$, in particular $n(\phi)(I)=0$. But $n(\phi)(I)=n(A)I=n(A)=0$, so any such $n(x)$ is divisible by $m(x)$. Therefore, $m(x)$ is also minimal for $\phi$.

The characteristic polynomials are different. Degree of characteristic polynomial of a transformation $\alpha\colon V\to V$ is the dimension of the space $V$. So $\deg(\chi_A)=n$ while $\deg(\chi_\phi)=n^2$. Here $\chi_\alpha$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of the correspondent linear transformation $\alpha$.